# I want to train model, it keeps on displaying errors

Tags: tensorflow

Here is my code, I have done a lot of research but I was not successfull. Please help me out.

```
DATA_PATH = "data.json"
SAVED_MODEL_PATH = "model.h5"
LEARNING_RATE = 0.0001
EPOCHS = 40
NUMBER_KEYWORD = 30
BATCH_SIZE = 32


def load_dataset(data_path):
    with open(data_path, "r") as fp:
        data = json.load(fp)
        # extract inputs and targets
        X = np.array(data["MFCCs"])
        Y = np.array(data["labels"])
        return X, Y


def get_data_splits(data_path, test_size=0.1, test_valuation=0.1):
    # load dataset
    X, Y = load_dataset(data_path)

    # create train/validation/test splits
    X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=test_size)
    X_train, X_validation, Y_train, Y_validation = train_test_split(X_train, Y_train, test_size=test_valuation)

    # convert inputs from 2D to 3D arrays
    X_train = X_train[..., np.newaxis]
    X_validation = X_validation[..., np.newaxis]
    X_test = X_test[..., np.newaxis]
    return X_train, X_validation, X_test, Y_train, Y_validation, Y_test


def build_model(input_shape, learning_rate, error="sparse_categorical_crossentropy"):
    # build the neural network
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu",
                                  input_shape=input_shape,
                                  kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001)))
    model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same"))
    # conv layer 2
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu",
                                  kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001)))
    model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same"))
    # conv layer 3
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (2, 2), activation="relu",
                                  kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001)))
    model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding="same"))

    # flatten the output feed it into dense layer
    model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))
    # softmax classifier
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(NUMBER_KEYWORD, activation="softmax"))
    # compile the model
    optimiser = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimiser, loss=error, metrics=["accuracy"])
    model.summary()
    return model


def main():
    X_train, X_validation, X_test, Y_train, Y_validation, Y_test = get_data_splits(DATA_PATH)
    # Building the model
    input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2], X_train.shape[3])
    model = build_model(input_shape, LEARNING_RATE)

    # model Training
    model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
              valuation_data=(X_validation, Y_validation))
    # evaluate model
    test_error, test_accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)
    print(f"Test_Error:{test_error}, Test_accuracy:{test_accuracy}")
    # Save the Model
    model.save(SAVED_MODEL_PATH)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here are the errors being displayed; actually I don't understand what this return method means

> return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
> TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'valuation_data'

Comment: Your code does not reproduce the above error. Please see how to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

For the error you are reporting, the only problem is the misspelled "validation_data" keyword argument (not "valuation_data") passed to the .fit() function.